# c# FluentValidation: SetInheritanceValidator with external dependencies

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

In FluentValidation, we can use `SetInheritanceValidator` to specify which subclass-validator to use, per https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/inheritance.html :

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    public int NrOfWheels { get; }
}

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    public int NrOfWheels => 4;
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}

public class Bicycle : IVehicle
{
    public int NrOfWheels => 2;
}
```

When validating our vehicles, we can specify the validators to be used for our subclasses:

```
public class VehicleValidator : AbstractValidator<IVehicle>
{
    public VehicleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).SetInheritanceValidator(v =>
            v.Add<Car>(new CarValidator(engineApi)); // Oh no! I don't have an EngineApi!
            v.Add<Bicycle>(new BicycleValidator());
        });
    }
}
```

However, my `CarValidator` needs the `EngineApi` to do its work! I don't want to pass an `EngineApi` to my `VehicleValidator` constructor, as I'm often checking `Bicycle` instances. None of the overloads of `PolymorpicValidator.Add` allow me to pass arguments. How can I get an `EngineApi` from the dependency injection engine when creating a `CarValidator`?

Comment: If you have validators that needs to be constructed by the DI container then don't new them ever. Just add an IValidation<Car> carValidator, IValidation<Bicycle> bikeValidator to the constructor of your VehicleValidator and then use those instances in your `Add` call. If one your validators later on now needs another parameter in their constructor you can do so without having to change your VehicleValidator.

Comment: That could work! However, I would need to add validators to my public constructors and I prefer not to do that: The usage of FluentValidation is an implementation detail, something I do not expose on the public interfaces to make refactoring easier. But your solution will work, as long as I can keep the validators off my public constructors...